# How to close a window group programmatically in SwiftUI macOS app?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Here's the example:

```
@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        MainScene()
        SecondScene()
    }
}

struct MainScene: Scene {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup(id: "mainscene") {
            Text("Main")
            Button("close") {
                // how to close current scene
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get current *WindowGroup* instance, so don't have any idea how to close current window programmatically.

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this is to have an ObservableObject singleton that you get throughout your views and make the `SecondScene` property conditional - that could "close" it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Access the current window by using: `NSApp.windows.first?` or `NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?`, but `NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?` will return `nil` when the window is not active.

```
struct MainScene: Scene {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup(id: "mainscene") {
            Button("close") {
                NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()
            }
            .task {
                NSApp.windows.first?.close()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. There doesn't seem to be any other way to hide a WindowGroup.